# Can I modify postgresql sql before execute it

Tags: postgresql, grafana, timescaledb

I use grafana to view metrics in timescaledb. 
For large scale metrics I create a view to aggregate them to a small dataset, I configure a sql in grafana, which table is fixed, I want the table name is changed according to the time range, say: time range less than 6 hours, query the detail table, time range greater than 24 hours query the aggregate view.
So I am looking for a proxy or postgresql plugin which can used to modify the sql before execute it.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no PostgreSQL extension to modify SQL query but there is a proxy that says it can rewrite and filter SQL query: https://github.com/wgliang/pgproxy.

Answer (score 0):

You might alternatively look at TimescaleDB's real-time aggregates, which were released in 1.7

Basically it will transparently take the "union" between pre-calculated aggregates > 6 hours with the "raw" data < 6 hours.

Not quite what you are asking for, but might get you to the same place, and works transparently with grafana.

https://blog.timescale.com/blog/achieving-the-best-of-both-worlds-ensuring-up-to-date-results-with-real-time-aggregation/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at [Gallium Data](https://www.galliumdata.com), it's a free database proxy that allows you to change database requests before they hit the database, and database responses before they reach the clients.

Disclosure: I'm the founder of Gallium Data.